# DeviceEventEmitter.addListener not working in Release apk in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class to send events from android native code to react native but DeviceEventEmitter.addListener is not listening in Release Apk. It is working perfectly fine in Debug Apk. I tested this on multiple devices. I'm using react-native v.0.66.3

```
private void sendEvent(String eventName, WritableMap params) {
        Log.v("Events", "DEBUG: Sending event from android to react" + ' ' + eventName + " " + params.toString());

        ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();
        ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();

        if(reactContext != null) {
            Log.v("Events", "DEBUG: not null" + reactContext);
            reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
        } else {
            Log.v("Events", "DEBUG: null: adding listened" + reactContext);
            reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
                    Log.v("Events", "DEBUG: inside listener" + context);
                    context
                        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                        .emit(eventName, params);
                    reactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And in React Native app.js file

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('accept', (event) => {
      //Do something
    });
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is looking for answer. I wasn't able to get the DeviceEventEmitter to work in the release version. For my specific use case, I took a different route and used Android's SharedPreferences to store the event data. And in the react-native, I used the useEffect hook (on mount) in the entry file and got the event data back from the SharedPreference using [react-native-shared-preferences](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences) library. After getting the data, I emptied the SharedPreference values.

Hope this helps